# Have I done this correctly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, uniform-convergence

I need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+x^2}$ converges uniformly but not absolutely on $\mathbb{R}$.

First, I showed that the absolute value of the partial sums diverges for any value of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by comparison to the harmonic series. But the series converges by the Alternating Series Test since $\frac{1}{n+x^2}$ is monotonically decreasing for any fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and it vanishes as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Then I proceed to use the Cauchy Condition to show that the series has bounded partial sums.  But this is where I think I messed up.  This is what I have.

$$\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+x^2}\right| \leq \left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{k}\frac{1}{n+x^2}\right| \leq \left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}\right| \leq \epsilon$$

My confusion is that while I know that the series partial sum I've bounded my series by is divergent, but I also know that my series is always less than it.  Am I doing anything right?

I fear that this is not quite correct.

Comment: You have proven that it converges, but not absolutely. What remains is to show that it's convergence is, in fact, uniform. Do you know the definition of uniform convergence?

Comment: I wonder if the $(-1)^n$ is supposed to be in the numerator...

Comment: silly me.  I'm new to this latex thing and I made typos gallore...

Comment: For fractions, use \frac{numerator}{denominator}

Comment: Abel's Uniform Convergence Test should work for this case: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsUniformConvergenceTest.html

Comment: But looking at that test, $a_{n} = (-1)^{n+1}$ is not convergent...

Comment: don't use $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ then. :D

Comment: I suppose Abel's Test maybe not be well suited to this problem, I think this property of metric spaces ($\mathbb{R}$ is a metric space) will do the job: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_Cauchy_sequence

Comment: One technicality with using that notion is that you need the codomain to be a complete metric space (and $\mathbb{R}$ is not complete). However, you should be able to find bounds so that $f(x)$ is always within a closed interval with those bounds as endpoints, and that subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is complete with the induced metric.

Comment: Dirichlet's test is applicable: $\sum a_n(x) b_n(x)$ converges uniformly if $\sum a_n(x)$ is uniformly bounded and $b_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly and monotonically. Here $a_n(x) = (-1)^{n+1}$ and $b_n(x) = 1 /(n + x^2) \leqslant 1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

So... I have the answer.  We can't easily bound the series using Cauchy's Condition.  The obvious choice of $\sum_{n=m+1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}$ doesn't have an upper bound.  It diverges.  Rather, there is a consequence of the Alternating Series Test that I missed, or ignored or forgot... the consequence is the following:

We know the series converges conditionally by the A.S.T.  So We can call the sum A.  If $s_n$ is the partial sum of our sereis, $$\left| A - s_{n}\right| \leq a_{n+1} $$  so we can make this more explicit:

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+x^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+x^2}\right| \leq \left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+x^{2}}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n+x^2} \leq \frac{1}{n} \leq \epsilon$$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

RRL's answer above using Dirichlet's Test also works and arrives at the same conclusion.  This answer just completes where I started off instead of starting over.